# $scope property undefined when INPUT is 'required'

Tags: javascript, angularjs

In this basic example of 2 `input` fields, I am updating the model on `blur`. The difference between the 2 fields is one has the `required` attribute and the other does not.

I'm watching for a change on the model and dumping out the `$scope.user` property. I have noticed that when the field is NOT required, I change the value from any string back to an empty string, and the model updates as empty. However, the required field updates as `undefined`.

I don't see anything particular in the docs that would cause this. Can anyone shed some light?

```
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="Ctrl">
    <input name="name" ng-model="user.name1" ng-model-options="{updateOn: 'blur'}" />
    <input name="name" ng-model="user.name2" ng-model-options="{updateOn: 'blur'}" required />
</div>
<script>
var app = angular.module("app", []);
app.controller("Ctrl", ["$scope", function ($scope) {
    $scope.user = {
        name1: "",
        name2: ""
    };

    $scope.$watchGroup(["user.name1", "user.name2"], function (value) {
        console.log($scope.user);
    });
}]);
</script>
```

[image]

http://jsfiddle.net/3h8o1yrz/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In AngularJS, if there are validations on an input, by default `ng-change` will not be fired unless all validations are passed.

However, you can alter this behavior by `ng-model-options` (https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngModelOptions).

Try this:

```
<input name="name" ng-model="user.name2" ng-model-options="{updateOn: 'blur', allowInvalid: true}" required />
```